# Testing the inviting of users to an event: event_id/invited/user_id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on testing some code to invite a user to an event when they click a button. Presently I'm doing this with test users. I created two test users on the app I'm developing. One of them I used to create a facebook event. The other created a facebook tab for the app. I'm trying to pass the event id and the id of the second user in

```
event_id/invited/user_id
```

as a post, so the user gets invited. However, i get the following JSON response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) ", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 200
  }
}
```

Is this impossible to do with test users? Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Test users have some visiblity limitations (i.e they effectively don't exist to non-test-users) - are the two users friends, and do you have the create_event permission for the one which is sending the invite?

Comment: No to the first question, they aren't friends, yes to the second question. I examined the access_token and could see the correct permissions in there. Now, it would seem while I cannot send out the invite for whatever reason, i was able to use the rvsp method with `POST event_id/attending`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test users being friends was a pretty key factor when testing this out. Be sure to do that if you want to send invites around such via FB :).